# Blender Won't Render Transparent Images Properly

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

So I'm new to blender, only been using it for a week. I've looked up a lot of tutorials and I'm trying to figure out how to make animations with it. Currently I have something set up like this:

[image: That's my set up, don't ask 'bout the animation. :L]

The materials and texture have alpha turned on, and I went to render. I tried looking at it through <kbd>F12</kbd> but this is what comes up:

Update: Turns out the light was making shadows, so I turned it off, but I still end up with this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: There should be several tutorials on Youtube, or I can get back to you if you're stuck.  Just leave a comment here.

Comment: Added to the above - Have you tried rendering with OpenGL?  It's way faster and what you see in the 3D window (viewport) is what will be rendered to video.

Comment: Well, I have tried youtube but none of them work. And I tried to get OpenGL but I can't seem to find a download link to it.

Comment: When your project is loaded, go to the left of the top of window.  Click on the "Render" option, then the OpenGL Render Animation.  That will use your hardware to render to video, what you see in your 3D window.